# Can't run mongodb because core-dump problem?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, coredump

I have a problem with Mongo after installation on Ubunto.
When I run a command

```
sudo systemctl status mongodb
```

And the result is

```
mongodb.service - An object/document-oriented database
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Fri 2018-09-21 15:32:19 +07; 49min ago
Docs: man:mongod(1)
Process: 5668 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --unixSocketPrefix=${SOCKETPATH} --config ${CONF} $DAEMON_OPTS (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)
Main PID: 5668 (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)
Thg 9 21 15:32:16 saymyname systemd[1]: Started An object/document-oriented database.
Thg 9 21 15:32:19 saymyname systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
Thg 9 21 15:32:19 saymyname systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
```

Please help me fix this problem!

Comment: Are you able to start the mongo server manually? Should be under /usr/bin/mongod. Remember to specify dbpath parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, maybe because of ubuntu upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04. Tried many things, at the end reinstalling mongodb worked. It was a new install so did not care about backups.

```
$ sudo apt remove mongodb mongo-tools mongodb-clients mongodb-server mongodb-server-core
$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mongodb/
$ sudo apt install mongodb
```

Comment: is this will remove data, or data still safe?

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact match for your issue, but close enough for googlers.

If the middle line of the 3 after the coredump is status `4/ILL`:

```
... mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=4/ILL
```

For MongoDB 5.0+

If you are running on VirtualBox with a Windows host, disable Hyper-V. The issue is a lack of AVX support and to get it you need to disable Hyper-V and be using VirtualBox 5.03 or later.

Using CMD as Administrator

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
DISM /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

Then hard shutdown and restart the host. After that, starting the guest from cold boot should work.

```
sudo systemctl start mongodb
sudo systemctl status mongodb
```

Source: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=99390